# call c function in c++

Tags: c++, c, c++11, compatibility, calling-convention

I try to create a wrapper class to wrap the c function `lmdif1` in library [cminpack](https://svn.personalrobotics.ri.cmu.edu/public/13.1/moped/BundlerPy/lib/cminpack/lmdif1.c)

```
class CSolver
{
public:
    void solve()
    {
        ...
        using namespace std::placeholders;
    auto f = std::bind(&CSolver::fcn, this, _1, _2, _3, _4, _5, _6);
        int32_t iRet = lmdif1(f, 0, m_iEqualCount, m_iUnknownVariableCount, x, fvec, tol, iwa, wa, lwa);
    }
private:
    int32_t fcn(void* p, int32_t m, int32_t n, const double* x, double* fvec,int iFlag)
    {
    ....
    }
};
```

Compile error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<int (CSolver::*)(void*, int, int, const double*, double*, int)>(CSolver*, std::_Placeholder<1>, std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>, std::_Placeholder<4>, std::_Placeholder<5>, std::_Placeholder<6>)>’ to ‘cminpack_func_mn {aka int (*)(void*, int, int, const double*, double*, int)}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int lmdif1(cminpack_func_mn, void*, int, int, double*, double*, double, int*, double*, int)’
         int32_t iRet = lmdif1(f, 0, m_iEqualCount, m_iUnknownVariableCount, x, fvec, tol, iwa, wa, lwa);
```

How can I solve it?

EDIT: So I will use a global function. Thank you all.

Comment: You're passing a C++ object to a C function. The C function simply has no idea what an "object" is, and will not be able to use it.

Comment: So the only way is to create a global function?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: How do you portably give a `static` member function `extern "C"` linkage? I realize that mangled name won't be used the calling conventions could differ (although in practice they don't).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, no, that is not valid, the callback takes an argument of type "pointer to `extern "C"` function" and a pointer `extern "C++"` function (such as a static member function) is not convertible to a pointer to an `extern "C"` function (although many compilers accept it)

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: As I said in the previous comment: the calling conventions _can_ differ: passing an `extern "C++"` function pointer where an `extern "C"` pointer is expected isn't guaranteed to work although I'm not aware of any system where it fails.

Comment: [From C++ to shining C](http://www.drdobbs.com/from-c-to-shining-c/184401694)

Comment: Yes you must create a global function (with "C" linkage). If you want to feed it extra data, you must use global data. The world ain't all sunshine and rainbows.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Answer (score 0):

You cannot take a function pointer of a member function. It must be a class function. Class functions are declared with the static keyword in C++. So all you have to do is change the prototype of fcn to:

```
static int32_t fcn (void *p, int32_t m, int32_t n, const double *x, 
   double *fvec, int iFlag)
```

Of course, you won't be able to access any non-static member variables from within fcn.

Hope this helps!